# create composite unique key using two foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

I am using MySQL as a database and working with JPA and want to create a table `quarter_level_result` in which i have two foreign key i.e. `quarter_id` and `department_id`. I want to design table such a way that combination of these two key should be unique.

so i code like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quarter_level_result",
       uniqueConstraints= {@UniqueConstraint(
                                columnNames = {"quarter_id", "department_id"})})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                  property  = "id", 
                  scope     = Long.class)
@DynamicInsert(true)
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class QuarterLevelResult implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6418708201861121181L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false )
    @JoinColumn(name = "quarter_id", unique = true)
    private QuarterLevel quarterLevel;

    @Transient
    private Long quarterId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "current_level")
    private Long currentLevel;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "current_cost")
    private Long currentCost;

    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", unique = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Departments departmentInfoForQuarterResult;

    @Transient
    private Long departmentId;

    // getters and setters
}
```

### Problem:

initially i inserted record with (quarter_id, department_id) =(1 ,2) it is working fine. after that i inserted another record (quarter_id, department_id) =(2 ,2) but this type i got an error duplicate entry `2` for department_id.

Answer (score 1):

just remove `unique = true` from the `@JoinColumn`: it is a shortcut to create a unique key for that column only.

The `@Table#uniqueConstraints` is sufficient.

Comment: Did you dropped the unique indexes from the db? if you are using `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` you have to do it manually.

Comment: Well, I'm sure it **must** work on a clean db and it's not hibernate anyway - it is your database which contains the wrong constraints. Try dropping and recreating the entire db and check that your build lifecycle is actually compiling and using the modified classes.

Comment: i dropped my schema but my problem is remain same